# using https with elasticsearch-php client

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I am currently trying to connect to my elastic search cluster using the [php elasticsearch client](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html)

I am having trouble using an `https` endpoint for this. I have my cluster behind a load balancer with a VIP in front, it is using Apache authentication and is on port 443. The trouble I am running into is that the config for the client seems to be parsing the hosts and removes `https://` from the host name. this results in the client always trying to connect over port 80. I have tried adding :443 to the host name but I am then getting a curl error "empty reply from server". I know that this server has access (no firewall blocking) because i can manually make the curl call using https://myelasticsearch.com.

My question is, is there a way to specify the protocol to make the request over using this client? if not, where in the source is the parsing of the host array happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a temporary solution, in `src/Elasticsearch/Connections/AbstractConnection.php` there is a defined `transportSchema` variable that is set to `http`. I changed this to `https` and also added the :443 to my host in the config and it works!

Answer (score 0):

Just as an update to this question (in case anyone stumbles into it), this bug was fixed in Elasticsearch-PHP v1.1.0.  You can specify `https` in the host now to use SSL:

```
$params = array();
$params['hosts'] = array (
    'https://localhost',        // SSL to localhost
    'https://192.168.1.3:9200'  // SSL to IP + Port
);

$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
```