# need help solving fatal error exception in Elastic search

Tags: php, exception, elasticsearch, fatal-error

i am new to elasticSearch please help me out. i have written the following test code in `php`

```
<?php
require '../../vendor/autoload.php';
$params = array();
    $params['hosts'] = array (
        'https://localhost',        // SSL to localhost
    );
$params['connectionParams']['auth'] = array(
    'root',
    '',
    'Basic' 
);
    $params1 = array(
        'index'  => 'test_missing',
        'type'   => 'test',
        'id'     => 1,
        'ignore' => 404 
    );
$client = new Elasticsearch\Client($params);
    echo $client->get($params1);
```

but am getting following fatal error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\Curl\CouldNotConnectToHost' with message 'Failed connect to localhost:9200; No error' in 
C:\xampp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\AbstractConnection.php:308 Stack trace: #0 
C:\xampp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection.php(307): Elasticsearch\Connections\AbstractConnection->throwCurlException(7, 'Failed connect ...') #1 
C:\xampp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection.php(197): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->processCurlError(Object(Guzzle\Http\Exception\CurlException)) #2 
C:\xampp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection.php(104): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->sendRequest(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Request), NULL) #3 
C:\xampp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Transport.php(166): Elasticsearch\Connections\GuzzleConnection->performRequest('GET', '/test_miss in C:\xampp\vendor\elasticsearch\elasticsearch\src\Elasticsearch\Connections\AbstractConnection.php on line 308
```

i am using xampp for php in windows 7
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your elastic search running?

Comment: try querying using sense and check whether it is working fine.

Comment: @Prateek sorry but i am new to this, can u point out what is `sense`

Comment: yes please, was about to ask the same

Comment: Sense is a javascript tool to query your elasticsearch. It runs in your browser. check [link]https://github.com/bleskes/sense and [link]https://www.found.no/foundation/Sense-Elasticsearch-interface/ and Online sense is available at [link]http://sense.qbox.io/gist/

Comment: @Prateek i used this sense.qbox.io/gist and put my url in to it "http://localhost/elasticsearch/es_14_7.php". but the page refreshes.

Comment: @dhpratik You should download sense zip from [link]https://github.com/bleskes/sense and after extraction run index.html. It will be connected to your local elastic search. Now you can give DSL query to check if your elastic search is Running. If you have elastic search on remote machine, provide machine name and port in server input box and click outside, it will get connected to that and then you can run your DSl query there.

Comment: What happens when you type localhost:9200 into your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not used https so am not 100% certain of the format for those connections, the code I have here does not specify a protocol within the hosts array (I have a different port number so have it appended to the host, it looks like that's optional but I have included it anyway):

$params['hosts'] = array('localhost:9200');

Beyond that the rest looks ok.

This question might help as well:
[using https with elasticsearch-php client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21391290/using-https-with-elasticsearch-php-client)